# how to write double nested for loops and not have a tuple as output

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For optimization purposes and education, I want to know how to write an optimized double nested loop. I tried a couple of options from other questions that looked similar but ran into a brick wall.

So I have an url that I am extracting text from and I am looping through the text to extract only the numbers and then sum them up and return the total.

Code:

```
import urllib
import re
from itertools import combinations

url = urllib.urlopen('http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/\
regex_sum_185517.txt')

total = 0

numlist = [re.findall('[0-9]+',line.rstrip()) for line in url]

#then I want to iterate through numlist twice to extract the numbers and sum them up.

for numb in numlist:
    for nu in numb:
        total = total + int(nu)

print total
```

I tried a couple of ways to optimize nested loops, but none of which gave me the desired output:

```
for nu in combinations(numlist,2):
    total = total + int(nu)
    print total
```

Returned:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

I also tried:

```
total = [[total + int(nu) for nu in numb] for numb in numblist]
print total
```

which returned the same nested list as in numlist. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: is the output of `total = [total + int(nu) for numbers in numlist for nu in numbers]` what you're looking for?

Comment: the sum of all the numbers extracted from the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard [flatten a single level of nesting pattern inlined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from future_builtins import map   # Only on Python 2 to avoid intermediate list
from itertools import chain

total = sum(map(int, chain.from_iterable(numlist)))
```